# Does Django support pgpool?

Tags: django, postgresql

Django db setting is

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'mydatabase',
        'USER': 'mydatabaseuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'mypassword',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

I want to know if I need to use `pgpool`
Should I need to change this settings ??

**update**

I try pgpool from this [website](http://jensd.be/591/linux/setup-a-redundant-postgresql-database-with-repmgr-and-pgpool)
And I found that there is no need to modify the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know Django, but I know pgPool: you can connect to it just like you do with the standard Postgres server, no special config is needed.

Comment: I try to find doc.But english is a little hard to me. I need to set postgresql replication first and then use pgpool.  Or does pgpool already have postgresql replication ??

Comment: If you are working on a master - slave configuration you must first setup streaming replication between the two servers. When replica is done, you can configure pg pool to act as a load balancer.

Answer (score 1):

Of course Django can connect and can use pgpool. If your pgpool is running on 127.0.0.1 at 5432 then for sure django can work with it. But I will recommend you not to use 5432 as pgppol port because it is the default port of postrgresql. You can use anyother port like 9999 or 7777 etc.

Follow this http://jensd.be/591/linux/setup-a-redundant-postgresql-database-with-repmgr-and-pgpool

to configure your postgresql in replication mode and failover.